# Changing Records to Show Horizontally instead of Vertically SQL Excel-VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm currently working in VBA for an excel report that I'm trying to make more automated. I've connected the worksheet to our database and was able to return the correct amounts and everything, but when I run the code, it returns the numbers in a vertical format instead of horizontal like I need it. Here is the current code that I have:

```
Cn.Open "DSN=" + db_name + ";UID=" + UserName + ";PWD=" _
& Password + ";"

FromDatex = Range("W39").Value
ToDatex = Range("X39").Value

Range("S7:AD9").ClearContents

          SQLStr = "SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(DATED,'MM')), SUM(VAL) FROM OPSAHISTM " & _
         "WHERE trunc(DATED) >=to_date('" & FromDatex & "','mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
         "AND trunc(DATED) <=to_date('" & ToDatex & "','mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
         "AND CUSTOMER = '03BA17'" & _
         "GROUP BY TRUNC(DATED,'MM') ORDER BY TRUNC(DATED,'MM')"

rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

With Range("S9")
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs

End With
rs.Close

    Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
```

End Sub

Any recommendations on how to have the results return horizontally would be wonderful.

Comment: There's a `transpose` method in excel if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `trunc` is not an SQL Server function

Comment: What is the transpose method?

Comment: Do you know which DBMS you are using? EXTRACT and TRUNC are Oracle functions. Is that the DBMS you are using?

Comment: Well, if your sql query is returning the correct output, then you need to show us the code that writes the results to the Excel sheet as well. Then someone can help in writing along a row instead of column.

Comment: MacroMarc, I edited my original post to include the rest of the relevant code. Does this help?

Comment: use @ to alert forum members, like @MacroMarc. i provided an answer below which shows how to do this. Have a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recordset like :

```
rs.Open yourCommand etc etc
```

start a loop

```
startCell = Range("S9")
rowNum = startCell.Row  '9
firstCol = startCell.Column  '19
i = 0
for each f in rs.Fields
    ws.cells(rowNum + i, firstCol).Value = f.name
    i = i + 1
next f
colNum = firstCol + 1
while Not rs.EOF
     for i = 0 to rs.Fields.Count - 1
          ws.cells(i + rowNum, colNum).Value = rs.Fields(i).Value
          colNum = colNum + 1
     next i
     rs.MoveNext
wend
.....
cn.close  'etc etc
.....
rs.close
set rs = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider transposing/pivoting in SQL using conditional aggregates with your original query as a derived table subquery:

```
SQLStr = "   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '01' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS JAN,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '02' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS FEB,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '03' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS MAR,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '04' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS APR,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '05' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS MAY,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '06' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS JUN,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '07' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS JUL,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '08' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS AUG,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '09' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS SEP,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '10' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS OCT,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '11' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS NOV,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " SUM(CASE WHEN valmonth = '12' THEN sumval ELSE NULL END) AS DEC"
SQLStr = SQLStr & " FROM"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "   (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(DATED,'MM')) AS valmonth,"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "           SUM(VAL) AS sumval"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "      FROM OPSAHISTM"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "     WHERE trunc(DATED) >= to_date('" & FromDatex & "','mm/dd/yyyy')"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "       AND trunc(DATED) <= to_date('" & ToDatex & "','mm/dd/yyyy')"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "       AND CUSTOMER = '03BA17'" 
SQLStr = SQLStr & "    GROUP BY TRUNC(DATED,'MM')"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "   ) AS dT"
```