# Transposing SQL Result in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm working in VBA in order to automate a report. I have the numbers coming through when I run the macro, but the numbers insert themselves vertically down the sheet and not horizontally across like I need them to. Here is the code I have so far (including the code to transpose it that is not working). What can I do to fix it to transpose?

```
FromDatex = Range("W39").Value
ToDatex = Range("X39").Value

Range("S7:AD9").ClearContents

        SQLStr = "SELECT SUM(VAL) FROM OPSAHISTM " & _
         "WHERE trunc(DATED) >=to_date('" & FromDatex & "','mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
         "AND trunc(DATED) <=to_date('" & ToDatex & "','mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
         "AND CUSTOMER = '03BA17'" & _
         "GROUP BY TRUNC(DATED,'MM') ORDER BY TRUNC(DATED,'MM')"


rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

With Range("S9:AD9")
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose ("S9:S11")


End With
rs.Close


    Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
```

Comment: What is the definition of `rs`?

Comment: This is what I put; is this what you mean?: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Comment: Please, improve a question. Do not forget to add the definition of `Cn` too.

Comment: Have you googled SQL rows to columns?

Comment: For cn: Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

Comment: I found a pivot function for sql, but the article I found was confusing and I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my code. I'm somewhat new to VBA/SQL/code in general and don't understand everything quite yet.

Comment: You have asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197265/changing-records-to-show-horizontally-instead-of-vertically-sql-excel-vba/37198348#37198348 . You have received an answer - you should address the same question rather than create duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways:

**Option 1:**  Use PasteSpecial>>Transpose (which is different than the `worksheetfunction.transpose`... not real sure what that formula does, honestly)

```
Range("S9:S11").Copy
Range("S8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

That will copy from `S9:S11` and paste it in `S8:U8`

**Option 2:**: Loop through your recordset and paste it horizontally. Instead of using `range.copyFromRecordset`, you copy your values from your recordset's field object manually while looping through each record in your recordset:

```
Dim writeCol as integer 'the column we are going to write to
writeCol = 19 'Starting at column S

'loop through the Recordset stopping at the last record
Do until rs.EOF
    'Drop into row 9, column writeCol, the value in the first field of your recordset for this record
    Sheet1.Cells(9, writecol).value = rs.Fields(1).value

    'Go to the next record in your record set
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Personally, I like the second option as it gives you more control and you aren't relying on the clipboard. It doesn't matter how many results are returned, it will just keep dropping them in columns until it hits an end to your recordset. The only downside with this option is that it will be slower if you have a lot of records returned, although, I'm betting if you had a lot of records returning, you probably wouldn't want to paste them in columns.